# Disable all dates if empty array is passed into enable parameter in Flatpickr

Tags: flatpickr

I just want to know, is there any way to disable all the dates, in case an empty array of dates is being passed into the enable parameter. Currently, I am passing few dates that fetched from the database, there are few cases, where it doesn't fetch any dates, in that scenario I want the calendar dates to be completely disabled. Is there anyway?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of flatpickr has an example there.
https://flatpickr.js.org/examples/#disabling-specific-dates

There are 3 possibilities:

1. Disabling specific date
2. Disabling a date range
3. Disabling dates using a function

Just follow their examples an you will succeed.

In your case i would use the disabling by a function an return true for every date if your array is empty.

Comment: I tried the same, doesn't work. If you pass an empty array of dates, it ignores and enables all the dates. Works similarly for both enable and disable params. Finally, I had to disable the input field based on the array passed. Anyway thanks.

Comment: no, you should set a function, pass your array there and if "dateArray.length===0" return true; so you disable every date if your array is emtpy

Comment: Correct, that is the way it should work, function should be passed when you need to do some other operations before passing the actual array to the enable param. I already have the array formed and when passed with dates, it shows those dates as enabled, but when the array is empty, none gets disabled. For your convenience, you can try to initialize a flatpickr instance and pass an empty array to the enable param and let me know how the calendar behaves.

Comment: i dont pass arrays to "enable" or "disable" config param. i have assigned a method which to the magic for me.
"disable": [
        function(date) {
            // return true to disable
            if (yourArrayWithDates.length === 0) return true;

        }
    ],

if you work with a SPA (aurelia, angular) just use an arrow function and access the property of your viewmodel like
disable = [
         (date) => {
          // return true to disable
           if (this.yourArrayWithDates.length === 0) return true;
        }]